# Google Maps Area Boundries

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I know there has been many similar questions along this line, but they're all multiple of years old and I want an answer that's more recent.

When you go to Google maps and type in a country / state / city etc you are shown a lovely red boundary line with a soft red filled in polygon.

eg:

[image: state boundry]

I'm hoping its as simple as a simple function call in the default Maps API.

I know there are other options using polygons from various websites.. but I was hoping there was a Google option.  If someone could help point this out to me.. that would be super great.

Comment: No such option exists yet.  You can vote for the [enhancement request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109) (looks like it was assigned to someone a few days ago, but don't get your hopes up)

Comment: Thanks geocodezip.  I had read several questions about this, but they were all 2+ years.  I had hope that in that time Google would have exposed the API to allow use to do it.  Talk about dropping the ball.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking to draw a lightly filled in polygon you can specify your own with the polygon function. There's an example on how to do it in the Maps API documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polygons

If you're looking for a call to automatically draw the boundary line from the search, then I'm not sure this exists yet.